# how to say ”(尤为)难得“ in English?

Tags: translation, word

How would you say "难得“ and ”尤为难得“ in English?

For example,

> 他在自己生活困难的情况下，资助老弱病残，尤为难得。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- "难“ means hard or difficult
- "得“ means to obtain

Combining the two, ”难得“ means something that is hard to come by.

- "尤为" (formal) means especially or particularly

Putting all together, "尤为难得" means especially hard to come by or a rarity.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase here means the people you mentioned before is rare. Becasue the people like that is nearly live in the textbook nowadays.
This phrase will have some difference when you use it on other situations.
You'd better note the context.
Here is some example.

尤为难得的是，石头左下角，草书提款“清女”二字，和画面主体遥相对应

“It's most precious that” it's signed in Chinese in the left hand corner "Qing Maid", which is in line with main content of the maid in Qing Dynasty

政治领导人有钱墨西哥总统路易斯.埃切维里亚，他曾毅然为中国恢复在联合国的合法席位投了赞成票，他被视为中国尤为难得的亲密朋友

Political leaders like former Mexico President Luis Echeverría, who voted affirmatively for restoration of China's lawful seat in the United Nations, were looked upon as close friends “particularly”

而真正推动英国经济发展的，可能是消费者这种“感觉不错”的心理——在今年，这种情绪尤为难得

The real boost to the economy, however, could come from creating a "feel-good factor" among consumers that “proved elusive” this year with the England team's dismal performance in the soccer World Cup

The original means or usage is someone who is rare in nowadays. Or means someone who has  good character which is rare and he also have another one which may be more unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Scarce is probably the best word. It means very hard, (but not impossible) to find

Edit for a more constructive answer.

Scarce may be used in the following contexts:

-Water can scarcely be found in the desert.

-Say, a popular new product is released, but sells out quickly, and the manufacturer cannot keep up with demand.  You might say "the *product* is going to be scarce for a while

-certain personality traits are scarce among people

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.

Answer (score 0):

难得：Even it is hard for somebody to do something, he do it. You can also consider this word '难得可贵' where '难得=可贵(valued, precious, applaudable)'.

尤为=especially.